# Protobuf map message option

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to append some documentation metainformation to a protobuf message by extending google.protobuf.MessageOptions. One of my metainfo option may appear more than once. Looks like I can declare map option but how can I use it on a message?

Here is an example of what I try to achieve:

```
extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
    optional string description = 51234;
    HeadersOption headers = 51235;
}

message HeadersOption {
    map<string, string> headers = 1;
}

message MyMsg {
    option (description) = "MyMsg description";
    option (headers) = ???
}
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen `map` used in a custom option from .proto. Not sure it is possible.